# how to query multi level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making lawyer simple app to calculate agents commission
we have two category of agents

1. first agent - who Brings new customers to the lawyer office
2. second agent - who Brings agent too and get commission

I am using asp.net identity, the best practice to create this relation to adding filed named Parent with type Application user as a collection in the application user class

```
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Parent { get; set; }
```

then create the relationship.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Parent)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("Id");
                    m.MapRightKey("ParentId");
                    m.ToTable("User_Parent");

                });
```

now I can get the parent of an agent but I am tried to get child's of the parent but couldn't found the best practice to do this

```
public ActionResult ViewAgent(string Id)
        {
            //Get selected agent with related data
            var Agent = _context.Users.Single(c => c.Id == Id);
            _context.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.Clients).Load();
            _context.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.Parent).Load();
            foreach (var item in user.Clients)
            {
                _context.Entry(item).Collection(c => c.Case).Load();
                foreach (var charge in item.Case)
                {
                    _context.Entry(charge).Collection(c => c.CaseCharge).Load();

                }
            }

            //select agent Child's of agent with related data
            // How can i query it ?? an error here but i am looking around
            var childs=  _context.Users.Where(u=>u.Parent.Select(p=>p.Id==Id))
            return View(user);
        }
```

I expected to query bypass Agent above to the new query as a parent then I can get the child's in list

Comment: There is a lot of not relevant information in your first paragraph. Please rewrite it and only share the important information. Please show the code of your entites too - only the important parts - and explain your wanted relations in one or two sentences.

Comment: Obligatory copy&paste: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Do you have a parentId field on users? This would be needed to help store the relationship in the database.  If so, try -> var child = _context.Users.Where(u=>u.ParentId==Id);

Comment: no i haven't created PrentID and EF generate the table with fields as shown above , and i think i can not add ParentID in users because Parent type is Collection of users not User

Comment: That is a lot of separate database hits to load things up. You should use `Include()` to do it in one step. There is a lambda syntax, or you could try `var userWithClientsParents = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Parents).Include("Clients.Cases.CaseCharges").Single(c => c.Id == Id)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all users having the same parent, try:

```
var usersWithParent = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Parents.Any(p => p.Id == myParentId)).ToList();
```

Also, see my comment about eagerly loading all your collections at once.